# Positioning a nav bar around text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage to put some academic/work related stuff on it, but can't seem to figure out how to just put some buttons around my text without the button's margin totally running into each other.

My issue is when I try to add a margin to my projects button, it pushes the contact info button down a line. Any suggestions?

Here's what I have:

**Please run code snippet in a full window**

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FF9940, white);
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px grey;
  background-color: #1E2752;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  color: #FCFCFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  right: -100px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #FF9940;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Isabelle Kreienbrink </title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Isabelle Kreienbrink </h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts" style="margin-left: 860px;">Contact Info</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you give some more explanation , what kind of border you added  , how much was it's value ?

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA did my code not post to the answer? my border is 2px. its in the li a { } CSS section.

Comment: typing error , i wanna say **margin**

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA so can you not see the code I have present? I had to hardcode the margin for the contact info button to 860 px to the left because I couldn't use the general styling I was using in my CSS sheets since It needed to go very far to the right.

Comment: i added an answer , and a stackBlitz link to see the result

Comment: is it working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `px` value for alignement, you can use `float:right` and `float-left` instead of them , but they are not working in your exemple , or to be more specific, only the `float:right`is not working, because that the width it is not taking 100% of the screen width , here's the fix : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jihnyk

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Isabelle Kreienbrink </title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Isabelle Kreienbrink </h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="right-button"><a href="#contacts" >Contact Info</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FF9940, white);
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px grey;
  background-color: #1E2752;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  color: #FCFCFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  right: -100px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #FF9940;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 23px;
  right: 23px;
  width: 100%
}

.right-button{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 47px
}
```

a small hint : you can add the same transition you added in hover to the normal class, to get the same transition when the mouse leaves the button

Comment: It does work! I don't quite understand why. How did the width affect my ability to use float? Thanks for your helpful solution. I marked your answer as correct.

Comment: thank's , it's just that `float` works insid your `div` , so if your `div` is too small or with an `auto` width , then you can't see the result of using `float`, but if you add some space to your `div` you can see the difference , good luck ^^